# Reading node in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My XML is -

```
<Env>
 <Header>
  <Party>
   <From>
    <Id>1101</Id>
   </From>
  </Party>
 </Header>
 <Body>
  <Order>
   <BCP>
    <Party>
     <Id>1101</Id>
    </Party>
   </BCP>
  </Order>
 </Body>
</Env>
```

My xsl reads an XPath expression and reaches the element .

```
/Env/Body/Order/BCP
```

I want to go back in my xml and read the value from element

```
/Env/Header/Party/From/Id
```

I tried it like this -

```
../../Header/Party/From/Id
```

But the value isn't coming. Please suggest.

Comment: What's wrong with just using the absolute path?

Comment: The value is not coming on using this path.

Comment: I believe I have your answer, but please could you provide a little more context in future (such as a relevant extract from your xsl document. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
../../../Header/Party/From/Id
```

../.. Takes you up two levels, which is the Body node (Order then Body).  Header is not a child of Body, it's a sibling, so you need to go up one more level (to Env) to be able to traverse it in that manner.

Comment: Thnks, But I have tried this also, but hard luck, I didnot get any value.

Comment: I tested it and was successful.  If you are still having problems, perhaps you could supply your xslt?